# Asynctask causes exception 'Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()'

Tags: android, android-asynctask, handler

I am working on an android application.In my activity I am using the following code.

```
LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult(){

        @Override
        public void gotLocation(Location location){
            //Got the location!




            Drawable marker = getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.currentlocationmarker);//android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on
            int markerWidth = marker.getIntrinsicWidth();
            int markerHeight = marker.getIntrinsicHeight();
            marker.setBounds(0, markerHeight, markerWidth, 0);
            MyItemizedOverlay myItemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(marker);
            currentmarkerPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                    (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

            currLocation = location;

            mBlippcoordinate = currentmarkerPoint;
            mBlippLocation = location;
            myItemizedOverlay.addItem(currentmarkerPoint, "", "");

            mBlippmapview.getOverlays().add(myItemizedOverlay);
            animateToCurrentLocation(currentmarkerPoint);


        }
    };


    MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
    myLocation.getLocation(this, locationResult);
```

I am using the above code to find location from gps or network .The `animateToCurrentLocation(currentmarkerPoint);` method contains a asynctask .So I am getting

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I bet you have some sort of dialog or toast in your asynctask :) You need to rearange your code so that you don't do network operations from UI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this error when you are trying to create and run an AsyncTask from a thread that has no Looper attached to it. The AsyncTasks needs a Looper to post its "task completed" message back on the thread that started the AsyncTask.

Now your real question: how to get a thread with a Looper? It turns out you already have one: the main thread. As the documentation also states, you should create and .execute() your AsyncTask from the main thread. The doInBackground() will then run on a worker thread (from the AsyncTask threadpool) and you can access the network there. The onPostExecute() will then be run on you main thread, after it has been posted there via the main thread's Handler/Looper.

Comment: @baske....I understood something..But No idea about how to fix my current problem..now my asynctask is called from thread. How can i make my asynctask task to work from main thread?...

Comment: If I understand you correctly you are now creating and executing your AsyncTask from a worker thread and you want to know how you can do that instead on the main thread? Well the cheesiest way I can think of is using the Activity's runOnUiThread() method.

Your current code (mockup code, not actually working ;-):

...
task = new AsyncTask();
task.execute()
...

Your new code:
...
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
@override
public void run() {
task = new AsyncTask();
task.execute();
});
...

Comment: Sorry for the crappy markup.. new to StackOverflow, so still have to get used to all the stuff the forum has to offer. Hope you can understand it. What it basically does is wrap you existing code in a Runnable and post this runnable on the main thread's handler.