# "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()" in AsyncTask

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I got a weird problem with an android activity : I re-used one of my previous activity that works well, but this time all I got is "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()"

I tried to debug, and everything in the async task is performing well but when I reach then end of onPostExecute() the error is raised.

So I tried to disable my process about the process dialog, the only change is that it's crashing on line upper.

Here is the code :

```
public class DateActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_date);

        ActionBar actionBar = this.getSupportActionBar();

        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.actionbar_titre_date));

        if (VerifConnexion.isOnline(this)) {


            this.mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, getResources().getString(R.string.loading),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.loading), true);

            new QueryForDateTask().execute(this.mProgressDialog, this, this.getApplicationContext());
        } else {

            ...
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
        }

    }



    private class QueryForDateTask extends
            AsyncTask<Object, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

        private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
        private Activity act;
        private Context context;

        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Object... o) {


            this.mProgressDialog = (ProgressDialog) o[0];
            this.act = (Activity) o[1];
            this.context = (Context) o[2];

            ArrayList<String> listeDate = this.parseJSON(this.startQuerying());


            return listeDate;

        }


        public JSONObject startQuerying() {

            JSONRequest jr = new JSONRequest();


            String from = getResources().getString(R.string.api_param_from);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.FRANCE);
            from += "=" + sdf.format(new Date());

            String url = getResources().getString(
                    R.string.api_dates_json);


            JSONObject jo = jr.getJSONFromUrl(url + "?" + from);

            return jo;

        }


        public ArrayList<String> parseJSON(JSONObject jsonObject) {

            ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();

            try {
                JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("dates");

                if (array != null) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        String type = array.getString(i);
                        l.add(type);

                    }    // fin parcours JSONArray

                }

            } catch (Exception _e) {

            }

            return l;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            // setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> lDate) {

            // Create items for the ListView
            DateAdapter adapter = new DateAdapter(this.context, R.layout.searchitem_date, lDate, this.act);
            // specify the list adaptor
            ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.list)).setAdapter(adapter);
            this.mProgressDialog.dismiss();


        }
    } // fin async
}
```

I tried this to replace the call to the AsyncTask :

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    QueryForDateTask task = new QueryForDateTask();
                    task.execute(DateActivity.this.mProgressDialog, DateActivity.this, DateActivity.this.getApplicationContext());
                }
            });
```

(like explained in [Asynctask causes exception 'Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721920/asynctask-causes-exception-cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-call) as far as I understood), but the result is exactly the same.

So I can't understand why it is not working in this activity despite all is ok for the other ones of the project.

Any clue ?

Thank a lot for all ideas :)

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace, and indicate what line in your code is "line upper".

Comment: you don't need `runOnUiThread` if your asynctask in invoked on the ui thread.

Comment: @Raghunandan : it seemed strange too, but I tried

Comment: as asked by @CommonsWare it would be better to post the full stack trace.

Comment: @CommonsWare : actually, I tried again and this time the error log told me about a nullPointerException in my adapter. It seems I just made you waste time about this. And I hate LogCat by the way. Thank you to both of you, but it was all my fault

Comment: @MarcDelerue is your asynctask an inner class of your activity class? if so you have access to member variables and the activity context in asynxtask

Comment: @Raghunandan : it is an inner class. I know i should access variables of my activity without problems, but my previous tries weren't a success. It will change soon :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a post to mark the trouble as resolved :

the adapter i used was buggy in parsing parameters and throwed a NullPointerException.
I just fixed it, the AsyncTask is now running without problem.